# Unable to get property 'visibility' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, html

i changed our site from HTML to HTML5. Now i have issues with our menu that gives below error:

> Unable to get property 'visibility' of undefined or null reference

any idea, how to solve it ?

```
function hidectxmenu()
{
    if(menu_shadow.style.visibility)
    menu_shadow.style.visibility = "hidden";
    if (menuobj.iefiltercapable)  
    if (menuobj.filters[0]) menuobj.filters[1].Apply();
    if(menuobj.style.visibility) 
    menuobj.style.visibility ="hidden";
    if (menuobj.iefiltercapable)  
    if (menuobj.filters[0]) menuobj.filters[1].Play();
    menuobj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Give us a clue. Which line? I guess menu_shadow.style or menuobj.style is undefined or null.

Comment: document.write('<div id="menu_shadow" class="ctx_menu_shadow"></div>');
document.write('<div id="dfltmenu" class="ctx_menu">');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like menu_shadow is undefined.  Check where you defined it.  Double check spelling.

Also, the `element.style.visibility` returns a string so if probably want to add a check against that string to return a boolean for your `if` condition.  You probably want to add `=== "visible"` to the end of what you have.

Also, to make your code more readable for yourself, and for me, indent for each `if` so we can tell at a glance where control flow is going, and use `{}`'s on your `if` blocks.